# How to run Eclipse with openJDK11?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

How must `eclipse.ini` look like to make Eclipse (Photon, 2018-09 or 2018-12) run on openJDK11?

I have installed openJDK 11.0.1 and Eclipse 2018-09. I have a folder with XML jars (which seem to be required by Eclipse):

```
javax.xml.libs/
 javax.activation-1.2.0.jar
 jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
 jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar
 jaxb-impl-2.3.1.jar
```

I have modified `eclipse.ini` to use the jdk and the libs:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.100.v20180827-1352.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.800.v20180827-1352
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
D:/bin/jdk-11.0.1/bin
-vmargs
-cp D:/bin/javax.xml.libs/*
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-DEFAULT,ALL-SYSTEM
# --add-opens=org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Starting Eclipse works but leads to the following errors in `workspace/.metadata/.log`. Removing the comment from line 21 in `eclipse.ini` prevents Eclipse from starting at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
!SESSION 2018-12-18 11:59:04.814 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745
java.version=11.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core 4 0 2018-12-18 11:59:06.177
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core [282]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.24.2.v20180904-2231"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [299]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
              org.apache.xmlrpc [71]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1685)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1558)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui 4 0 2018-12-18 11:59:06.199
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui [284]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core; bundle-version="3.24.2.v20180905-0003"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core [282]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.24.2.v20180904-2231"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [299]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
                     org.apache.xmlrpc [71]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1685)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1558)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc 4 0 2018-12-18 11:59:06.223
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [299]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
       org.apache.xmlrpc [71]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1685)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1558)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 4 0 2018-12-18 11:59:11.498
!MESSAGE Unexpected error while loading repository template extensions
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 4 0 2018-12-18 11:59:11.498
!MESSAGE Could not load repository template extension contributed by 'org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ide' with connectorKind 'bugzilla'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2018-12-18 11:59:18.414
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.model.url.IntroURL.switchToLaunchBar(IntroURL.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.model.url.IntroURL.doExecute(IntroURL.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.model.url.IntroURL.lambda$0(IntroURL.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.model.url.IntroURL.execute(IntroURL.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.presentations.BrowserIntroPartLocationListener.changing(BrowserIntroPartLocationListener.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE.lambda$6(IE.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventTable.sendEvent(OleEventTable.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.notifyListener(OleEventSink.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.Invoke(OleEventSink.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.access$1(OleEventSink.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink$1.method6(OleEventSink.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3559)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2018-12-18 12:04:15.682
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Polling news feeds".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.commons.notifications.feed.FeedReader.parse(FeedReader.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl.poll.DefaultFeedItemStore.parseNewsItems(DefaultFeedItemStore.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl.poll.DefaultFeedItemStore.udpate(DefaultFeedItemStore.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl.poll.DefaultNewsPollingService.fallbackToLocalStore(DefaultNewsPollingService.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl.poll.DefaultNewsPollingService.poll(DefaultNewsPollingService.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl.poll.DefaultNewsPollingService.poll(DefaultNewsPollingService.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.news.rcp.poll.PollFeedsJob.run(PollFeedsJob.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext cannot be found by org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed_1.16.0.v20180904-2231
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 8 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2018-12-18 12:09:15.684
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Polling news feeds".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.commons.notifications.feed.FeedReader.parse(FeedReader.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl.poll.DefaultFeedItemStore.parseNewsItems(DefaultFeedItemStore.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl.poll.DefaultFeedItemStore.udpate(DefaultFeedItemStore.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl.poll.DefaultNewsPollingService.fallbackToLocalStore(DefaultNewsPollingService.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl.poll.DefaultNewsPollingService.poll(DefaultNewsPollingService.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl.poll.DefaultNewsPollingService.poll(DefaultNewsPollingService.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.news.rcp.poll.PollFeedsJob.run(PollFeedsJob.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: You probably want to use Eclipse 2018-12 which is released tomorrow, this should fix java.xml.bind problems - see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539515

Comment: That looks quite promising although Eclipse 2018-12 RC1 still shows the same errors. I will try it then by tomorrow. Thx for the info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug is caused by the Mylyn Bugzilla connector using classes of the `javax.xml.bind` package that has been introduced in Java 6, but removed in Java 11 (see: [JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320)).

In Eclipse, the Bugzilla connector is used for the following features that are broken when the mentioned error is logged each time Eclipse is started:

- *Help > Report Bug or Enhancement...*
- *Search > Search...*, tab *Task Search*

Unfortunately, this **bug still exists in Eclipse 2018-12 in some of the IDE packages**, including the *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers* you use (in your log as `-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product`).

Use one of the following as a workaround (tested with Eclipse 2018-12):

- Use [Java 8, 9 or 10 to run Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM), but in *Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs* use a Java 11 JDK
- Use the ***Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers*** instead of the *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers*
- Copy the following JARs from [Eclipse Orbit](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20181128170323/) **into the `dropins` folder** of your Eclipse 2018-12 IDE:

  - [**javax.xml.bind 2.2.0**](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20181102183712/repository/plugins/javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar)
  - [**javax.activation 1.1.0**](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20181102183712/repository/plugins/javax.activation_1.1.0.v201211130549.jar)
  - [**javax.xml 1.3**](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20181102183712/repository/plugins/javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400.jar)

For details see my (for 2018-12 unfortunately too late) mails on the Eclipse cross-project-issues-dev mailing list [here](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg16288.html) and [here](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg16292.html).

Comment: seems to be still virulent in 2019-6, dropping the referenced jars helped