# Target definition picks up Orbit source bundle but not the binary in Tycho build

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, tycho

An extract from the target definition:

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
    <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20200529191137/repository"/>
    <unit id="org.junit" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="javax.xml.soap" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="javax.xml.ws" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="javax.xml.bind" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="javax.jws" version="0.0.0"/>
    <unit id="javax.activation" version="0.0.0"/>
</location>
```

After reloading the target platform in Eclipse, all the compiler errors are resolved. It seems like everything was correctly loaded.

However, when the Tycho build runs, the `javax.jws.source` bundle is downloaded and the compile action fails.

```
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: com.grubra.atf.tycho:com.grubra.atf.admin.grubra:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\if12\git\com.grubra.atf.master\bundles\com.grubra.atf.admin
.grubra\.polyglot..META-INF_MANIFEST.MF
[INFO] Fetching &countryCode=de&timeZone=1&format=xml from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?format=xml&file=/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20191115185527/repository/
[INFO] Fetching javax.jws.source_2.0.0.v201005080400.jar.pack.gz from http://eclipse.c3sl.ufpr.br/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20191115185527/repository/plugins/ (13,3kB)
[INFO] Fetching 202003181000&countryCode=de&timeZone=1&format=xml from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?format=xml&file=/releases/2020-03/
[INFO] Fetching javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar.pack.gz from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03/202003181000/plugins/ (55,41kB)
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:2.0.0:compile (default-compile) on project com.grubra.atf.model: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\Users\if12\git\com.grubra.atf.master\bundles\com.grubra.atf.model\src\com\grubra\atf\office\IOfficeService_BasicHttpBindingIOfficeService_Client.java:[13]
[ERROR]         import javax.jws.WebMethod;
[ERROR]                ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The import javax.jws cannot be resolved
```

Why is `javax.jws.source` being downloaded instead of the binary? The download works fine for all the other bundles.

[Eclipse and Tycho are both running on Java 11. I am using Tycho 2.0.0 and Maven 3.6.0]

Comment: The source bundle is downloaded probably because of `includeSource="true"`. With which Java, Maven and Tycho version is this? Do you get the same result with Java 11 or higher, Maven 3.6.3 and Tycho 2.0? (The only thing I can think of is that this might be caused by running Maven with Java 8, where the packages are available in the system library too.)

Comment: Eclipse and Tycho are both running on Java 11. I am using Tycho 2.0.0 and Maven 3.6.0

Comment: You mean Maven 3.6.3, not Maven 3.6.0 (since [Tycho 2.0 requires Maven 3.6.3](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/2.0#New_and_Noteworthy)).

Comment: Ok good to know. I will upgrade. I just set `includeSource=false` (has to be for all locations) and I now get `javax.jws`. Strange that all the other bundles loaded ok.